Different result in linting errors in GitHub Actions and locally
I am working on a project. Here are my config files.
.github/workflows/linting.yaml
name: Go Lint CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  lint:
    name: Lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          go-version: '1.22.2'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          go mod download
          go mod tidy

      - name: Install golangci-lint
        run: |
          curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.51.2
          golangci-lint --version

      - name: Run golangci-lint on PR
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: |
          golangci-lint run --new-from-rev ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }} --config .golangci.yaml
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Run golangci-lint on main branch push
        if: github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
        run: |
          golangci-lint run --config .golangci.yaml
        continue-on-error: true

    #   - name: Display golangci-lint results
    #     if: failure()
    #     run: cat golangci-lint.log

The lint config file .golangci.yaml:
# Reference: https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/blob/master/.golangci.reference.yml
run:
  concurrency: 4
  timeout: 10m # Timeout for analysis
  issues-exit-code: 2 # Exit code when at least one issue was found.
  tests: true # Include test files or not
  modules-download-mode: readonly # Don't update the go.mod file
  allow-parallel-runners: true
  allow-serial-runners: true
  go: '1.19'
output:
  formats:
  - format: colored-line-number

  print-issued-lines: false # Print lines of code with issue.
  print-linter-name: false # Print linter name in the end of issue text.
  sort-results: true # Sort results by the order defined in `sort-order`.
  sort-order: # filepath, line, and column.
  - linter
  - severity
  - file
  show-stats: true # Show statistics per linter.

linters:
  disable-all: true

  enable:
  # bugs/error
  - staticcheck
  - revive
  - govet
  - errcheck
  - gosec
  - dupl

  # performance
  - gocritic
  - prealloc

  # style, formatting
  - stylecheck
  - staticcheck
  - goconst
  - gofmt
  - tagliatelle
  - decorder
  - lll

  # Code complexity
  - cyclop

linters-settings:

  # Error check settings
  errcheck:
    # Report about not checking of errors
    check-type-assertions: true # type assertions: `a := b.(MyStruct)`
    check-blank: true # `num, _ := strconv.Atoi(numStr)`

  # Gofmt settings
  gofmt:
    simplify: false
    rewrite-rules:
    - pattern: 'interface{}'
      replacement: 'any'
    - pattern: 'a[b:len(a)]'
      replacement: 'a[b:]'

  copyloopvar:
    # Linting error to assign a loop variable into another
    check-alias: true

  # Code complexity settings
  cyclop:
    # The maximal code complexity to report.
    # Default: 10
    max-complexity: 10
    # The maximal average package complexity.
    # If it's higher than 0.0 (float) the check is enabled
    # Default: 0.0
    package-average: 0.5
    # Should ignore tests.
    # Default: false
    skip-tests: false

  # Code organisation
  decorder:
    # Required order of `type`, `const`, `var` and `func` declarations inside a file.
    # Default: types before constants before variables before functions.
    dec-order:
    - type
    - const
    - var
    - func

    ignore-underscore-vars: false # Allow variables with underscore
    disable-dec-order-check: false # Disable order of declaration
    disable-dec-num-check: false # Multiple declaration of `type`, `var` and `const` not allowed

  # Golang security settings
  gosec:
    # To select a subset of rules to run.
    # Available rules: https://github.com/securego/gosec#available-rules
    # Default: [] - means include all rules
    includes:
    - G101 # Look for hard coded credentials
    - G102 # Bind to all interfaces
    - G103 # Audit the use of unsafe block
    - G104 # Audit errors not checked
    - G106 # Audit the use of ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey
    - G107 # Url provided to HTTP request as taint input
    - G108 # Profiling endpoint automatically exposed on /debug/pprof
    - G109 # Potential Integer overflow made by strconv.Atoi result conversion to int16/32
    - G110 # Potential DoS vulnerability via decompression bomb
    - G111 # Potential directory traversal
    - G112 # Potential slowloris attack
    - G113 # Usage of Rat.SetString in math/big with an overflow (CVE-2022-23772)
    - G114 # Use of net/http serve function that has no support for setting timeouts
    - G201 # SQL query construction using format string
    - G202 # SQL query construction using string concatenation
    - G203 # Use of unescaped data in HTML templates
    - G204 # Audit use of command execution
    - G301 # Poor file permissions used when creating a directory
    - G302 # Poor file permissions used with chmod
    - G303 # Creating tempfile using a predictable path
    - G304 # File path provided as taint input
    - G305 # File traversal when extracting zip/tar archive
    - G306 # Poor file permissions used when writing to a new file
    - G307 # Poor file permissions used when creating a file with os.Create
    - G401 # Detect the usage of DES, RC4, MD5 or SHA1
    - G402 # Look for bad TLS connection settings
    - G403 # Ensure minimum RSA key length of 2048 bits
    - G404 # Insecure random number source (rand)
    - G601 # Implicit memory aliasing of items from a range statement
    - G602 # Slice access out of bounds


  revive:
    # Maximum number of open files at the same time.
    # See https://github.com/mgechev/revive#command-line-flags
    # Defaults to unlimited.
    max-open-files: 2048

  lll:
    line-length: 120
    tab-width: 1

  staticcheck:
    # SAxxxx checks in https://staticcheck.io/docs/configuration/options/#checks
    # Default: ["*"]
    checks: ["all"]

When I run the linter locally:
$ golangci-lint run --config .golangci.yaml --verbose

I get the following result.
INFO [config_reader] Used config file .golangci.yaml
INFO [lintersdb] Active 15 linters: [cyclop decorder dupl errcheck goconst gocritic gofmt gosec govet lll prealloc revive staticcheck stylecheck tagliatelle]
INFO [loader] Go packages loading at mode 575 (compiled_files|deps|exports_file|files|types_sizes|imports|name) took 85.755667ms
INFO [runner/filename_unadjuster] Pre-built 0 adjustments in 535.708µs
INFO [linters_context/goanalysis] analyzers took 0s with no stages
INFO [runner/max_same_issues] 3/6 issues with text "multiple \"type\" declarations are not allowed; use parentheses instead" were hidden, use --max-same-issues
INFO [runner] Issues before processing: 41, after processing: 17
INFO [runner] Processors filtering stat (out/in): path_shortener: 17/17, exclude: 41/41, uniq_by_line: 22/28, max_same_issues: 17/20, path_prettifier: 41/41, exclude-rules: 28/41, skip_dirs: 41/41, autogenerated_exclude: 41/41, max_from_linter: 17/17, cgo: 41/41, filename_unadjuster: 41/41, invalid_issue: 41/41, diff: 22/22, max_per_file_from_linter: 20/22, source_code: 17/17, severity-rules: 17/17, fixer: 17/17, skip_files: 41/41, identifier_marker: 41/41, nolint: 28/28, path_prefixer: 17/17, sort_results: 17/17
INFO [runner] processing took 1.591206ms with stages: exclude-rules: 603.958µs, nolint: 347.459µs, identifier_marker: 324.667µs, path_prettifier: 103.042µs, autogenerated_exclude: 98.042µs, source_code: 61.416µs, skip_dirs: 23.583µs, max_same_issues: 10.625µs, uniq_by_line: 5.125µs, sort_results: 3.333µs, max_from_linter: 2.291µs, cgo: 1.624µs, invalid_issue: 1.416µs, max_per_file_from_linter: 1.125µs, path_shortener: 1.124µs, diff: 916ns, filename_unadjuster: 625ns, exclude: 292ns, fixer: 250ns, skip_files: 209ns, severity-rules: 42ns, path_prefixer: 42ns
INFO [runner] linters took 153.771625ms with stages: goanalysis_metalinter: 152.144541ms
cmd/root.go:1:1: the average complexity for the package cmd is 1.000000, max is 0.500000
internal/app/home/view.go:1:1: the average complexity for the package home is 1.592593, max is 0.500000
logger/logger.go:1:1: the average complexity for the package logger is 1.300000, max is 0.500000
main.go:1:1: the average complexity for the package main is 3.000000, max is 0.500000
internal/app/home/model.go:17:1: multiple "const" declarations are not allowed; use parentheses instead
internal/app/home/model.go:22:1: multiple "type" declarations are not allowed; use parentheses instead
internal/app/home/model.go:27:1: multiple "type" declarations are not allowed; use parentheses instead
internal/app/home/model.go:34:1: multiple "type" declarations are not allowed; use parentheses instead
logger/logger.go:14:1: type must not be placed after var (desired order: type,const,var,func)
internal/app/home/banner.go:38:6: Error return value of `colorful.Hex` is not checked
internal/app/home/banner.go:39:6: Error return value of `colorful.Hex` is not checked
internal/app/home/update.go:19:3: singleCaseSwitch: should rewrite switch statement to if statement
logger/logger.go:83: File is not `gofmt`-ed `-r 'interface{} -> any'` `-r 'a[b:len(a)] -> a[b:]'`
internal/app/home/home.go:20:16: G404: Use of weak random number generator (math/rand instead of crypto/rand)
internal/app/home/model.go:12:2: ST1003: should not use ALL_CAPS in Go names; use CamelCase instead
internal/app/home/model.go:13:2: ST1003: should not use ALL_CAPS in Go names; use CamelCase instead
internal/app/home/model.go:14:2: ST1003: should not use ALL_CAPS in Go names; use CamelCase instead
17 issues:
* cyclop: 4
* decorder: 5
* errcheck: 2
* gocritic: 1
* gofmt: 1
* gosec: 1
* stylecheck: 3
INFO File cache stats: 8 entries of total size 10.8KiB
INFO Memory: 4 samples, avg is 44.0MB, max is 59.6MB
INFO Execution took 245.35775ms

But in the GitHub Actions panel, I get an entirely different set of errors:
https://github.com/MayukhSobo/Spectacle/actions/runs/9132646511/job/25114413366
As far as I can see, the config is loaded successfully. So what could be the problem?

The problem arises from differing versions of golangci-lint on your local machine and within GitHub Actions.
GitHub Actions installs golangci-lint v1.51.2, which was compiled using Go 1.20. This version does not support features introduced in Go 1.22, as indicated by the following errors in GitHub Actions panel:
Error: ../../../../../opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.22.2/x64/src/bufio/bufio.go:54:23: undefined: max
...
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

To resolve this, update the version of golangci-lint to v1.59.1 in the "Install golangci-lint" step of your GitHub Actions.
